# How Do You Compile C++ Code Using Vim (Windows)?

Tags: c++, vim

So I've been searching for literally hours but I can't find a good way to compile my C++ codes through GVIM. So I've tried to compile my programs through Window's Command Prompt, but it didn't work out too well because I had to move my files around, which I didn't enjoy at all. I also tried using the `:make` function in GVIM which for some reason also didn't work. So can someone please just give a detailed instruction on how I can run my C++ codes while using VIM? Thanks!

P.S. There's a YouTuber that I watch and this was what I meant when I was wondering about compiling code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGrBHohIgQY        << Fast Forward to 1:20

Comment: Compiling is covered in chapter 30.1 of the user manual: `:help 30.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make own Makefile? `:make` will work only when you have created that file.